# Centering image with Javascript dosn't work in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, webkit, centering

i have i little problem my portfolio has a picture of me on it that keep 100% height and i want to center it with margin: 0 auto; in javascript. This works in IE (for once) but dosn't work in webkit browser.

my portfolio can be found on www.koenvrij.nl

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your problem is about css not javascript. and please post some code that gives your html and css structure. I'm not gonna lose my time to enter your site and elucidate what's wrong if you can't lose 5 minutes formulating a example.

Answer (score 2):

1) Your image needs to be `display: block;` for `margin: 0 auto;` to work.

2) You have an inline style with `margin-left: 0px;`. That's gonna cause problems

3) You have a bunch of other crap in the image's parent container, so it's going to center it in the remaining, unfilled area (not the entire area).

Comment: IIRC, you also need a specified fixed `width` when using `margin: 0 auto` (although that may be unnecessary for an image?).

Comment: Yeah. I think that's not necessary for images. The browser determines a width on it's own. One of the few elements where the default width is `auto`, yet doesn't have a fluid width. I'd say this is sort-of an edge case.

Comment: i forgot to mmention that i i'm centering the image with left: 50%; and than margin the half of the image but somehow it dosn't get the hals of the image.